# Inherit from table returned from function

Tags: oop, object, lua, lua-table

There is an API provided function, let's call it `createBase` which returns a table (object). I want to add methods to this table, but I can't just do `x = createBase()` and then `function x:foo()` because I have another function similar to `createBase`, but it's `createExtended`. It might be easier to explain with the code I have so far:

```lua
import api --I don't know how you'd do this in vanilla Lua, I'd use os.loadAPI("api") but that's computercraft specific, I think
Extended = {}
function Extended:foo()
    print("foo from extended")
end

function createExtended(params)
    x = api.createBase(params)
    Extended.__index = x
    return Extended --this is obviously wrong: you can't return a class and expect it to be an object
end
```

Of course, this doesn't work: but I don't know how I might make it work either. Let's assume the table returned by `createBase` has a function called `bar` which just prints `bar from base`. With this test code, the following outputs are given:

```lua
e = createExtended()
e.foo() --prints "foo from extended"
e.bar() --nil, therefor error
```

How can I make this possible, short of defining `function x.bar()` inside `createExtended`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very simplest way is to attach the method to it directly, instead of using a metatable.

```lua
local function extend(super_instance)
    super_instance.newMethod = newMethod
    return super_instance
end

local function createExtended(...)
    return extend(createSuper(...))
end
```

This will work, unless your superclass uses `__newindex` (for example, preventing you from writing to unknown properties/methods), or iterates over the keys using `pairs` or `next`, since it will now have an additional key.

If for some reason you cannot modify the object, you will instead have to 'wrap' it up.

---

You could make a new instance which "proxies" all of its methods, properties, and operators to another instance, except that it adds additional fields and methods.

```lua
local function extend(super_instance)
    local extended_instance = {newMethod = newMethod}
    -- and also `__add`, `__mul`, etc as needed
    return setmetatable(extended_instance, {__index = super_instance, __newindex = super_instance})
end

local function createExtended(...)
    return extend(createSuper(...))
end
```

This will work for simple classes, but won't work for all uses:

Table iteration like `pairs` and `next` won't find the keys from the original table, since they're not actually there. If the superclass inspects the metatable of the object it is given (or if the superclass is actually a userdata), it will also not work, since you'll find the extension metatable instead.

However, many pure-Lua classes will not do those things, so this is still a fairly simple approach that will probably work for you.

---

You could also do something similar to Go; instead of having a way to 'extend' a class, you simply embed that class as a field and offer convenience to directly calling methods on the wrapping class that just call the methods on the 'extended' class.

This is slightly complicated by how 'methods' work in Lua. You can't tell if a property is a function-that-is-a-property or if it's actually a method. The code below assumes that all of the properties with `type(v) == "function"` are actually methods, which will usually be true, but may not actually be for your specific case.

In the worst case, you could just manually maintain the list of methods/properties you want to 'proxy', but depending on how many classes you need to proxy and how many properties they have, that could become unwieldy.

```lua
local function extend(super_instance)
    return setmetatable({
        newMethod = newMethod, -- also could be provided via a more complicated __index
   }, {
        __index = function(self, k)
            -- Proxy everything but `newMethod` to `super_instance`.
            local super_field = super_instance[k]
            if type(super_field) == "function" then
                -- Assume the access is for getting a method, since it's a function.
                return function(self2, ...)
                    assert(self == self2) -- assume it's being called like a method
                    return super_field(super_instance, ...)
                end
            end
            return super_field
        end,
        -- similar __newindex and __add, etc. if necessary
    })
end

local function createExtended(...)
    return extend(createSuper(...))
end
```

Comment: ooohhhh I didn't know it was possible to do x.function = alreadyDefinedFunction! That's so helpful, thanks!

Comment: `function a:b(c, d) ...... end` is just sugar for `a.b = function(self, c, d) ...... end`!

Comment: Yeah I never knew that and it seems very useful! The only other language I know (I don't know many) that has that kind of behaviour is python: a function is just a datatype if I remember correctly.